# Compile C++ program inside aws lambda custom runtime (C++ custom runtime)

Tags: c++, aws-lambda

I followed https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-c-lambda-runtime/ and able to run a simple hello world program.

My requirement is to compile another C++ program using the custom runtime.

let's say I have hello_world.cpp program and I am trying to compile it with:

```
system(g++ /tmp/hello_world.cpp -o /tmp/hello.out)
```

I also tried :

```
system(/usr/bin/g++ /tmp/hello_world.cpp -o /tmp/hello.out)
```

which gives error no such file or directory g++.

Can you help me installing C++ compiler inside C++ custom runtime or guide me how to add it inside deployment package, so I can use in my custom runtime.

Comment: I think you cannot add a custom runtime in AWS Lambda due to its design, if you want to manage that you might need to create a VM.

Comment: I am not sure if that is true, aws provides a way to add external dependencies https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-linux-binary-package/, but I am not able to make use of it to add C++ compiler.